# concensus between transaction processing and hash rate in ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

Is there a way to link mining and transaction processing in Ethereum?

E.g. 10 full nodes, private network, 100,000 transactions for all nodes per day. Load equally distributed; I have 10 systems/nodes with 2gb RAM each and i7 cpus.

Can I say I need **this much computing power**/no. of transaction per second to process them all with given gas -
it would take **x hours** for 100k transactions on 10 full nodes?

Is it possible to link transaction processing and hash rate in this manner?

A typical use case with following details would help:

- Gas Limit: could be customized as required.
- Block difficulty: could be as low as required.
- No. of transactions per day: 100 k
- No. of full nodes: 10
- Processing capabilities per node: 2 gb ram, 100 gb harddisk,
  processor i7

How many transactions could be processed per day, with these specs?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. But I don't see why the hashrate should be linked to the number of transactions. At 100k transactions it should does not really have impact on the block creation. Let's do the math.

- Default Gas Limit 4712388
- Minimum Transaction Fee 21000 Gas
- That's 4712388 / 21000 = 225 Transactions per Block
- Average Blocktime is currently around 14 seconds
- That's 60 * 60 * 24 / 14 = 6172 Blocks per Day
- That's 6172 * 225 = 1388700 Transactions per Day

1388700 transactions a node could process per day without taking scalability (gas limit increase by 1/1024 per block) into account.

- 100000 / 1388700 * 24 = 1.73 Hours

It takes 1.73 hours to process around 100k transactions for the network. Again, scalability ignored. The number of transactions should not affect the time between blocks. Also, it does not require a higher hashrate to process more blocks, as the proof-of-work's hard work is agnostic to the transactions.

I hope that answers your question. A signle node on a private network should be able to do it, as long as you don't run it on some small device like a raspberry pi.

Comment: how can this be done . I am using single node private chain with 8 gb RAM , 4 core cpu . My system hang at 28 tps . ref :http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11280/my-system-get-hang-while-i-do-more-than-27-transaction-in-a-second

Comment: Please  answer this question . How can we do this .

Comment: @Himanshusharma All you need is better hardware. 28 tps is already insane. What are you trying to do anyways?

Comment: Actually i am a creating a user contract verification app , so on that i  have to create contract and execute the function .So user can be many they can do transaction(execute function of contract and create contract). Blockchain i am using as the prove of contract action .

Comment: How much machine configuration i need to achieve this?