# Call Smart Contract every 5 Second

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible the call a method of a smart contract every 5 seconds? Lets say i want to call a webservice or an other smart contract in order to get the actual value?

That is not possible or? In this case on every node in the world this piece of code will run every 5 seconds  - with this mehtod i could crash every node or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases a [call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/765/87) is a passive action, just reading out the state of a contract. And the nodes in the network will not even recognize your *call*.

If you need to interact with the contract somehow, i.e., manipulating variables or similar, you need to create transactions. And of course it is possible to create a transaction every 5 seconds as long as you pay the [gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3/87).

Nodes will probably not crash if you create a transaction every 5 seconds. Other users [here on stack exchange try to breach](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11280/87) 30 transactions *per second*, this is about the practical range where verifying nodes will get in trouble.

Comment: Regarding executing a transaction every X seconds, it can be achieved by using ethereum alarm clock -
http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com

Comment: Thx for the answer -> is it also possible that a contract calls an other contract every 5 second in order to change a state? is already answered: ethereum-alarm-clock.com

Answer (score 3):

Public Ethereum network is designed to withstand any kind of load. It would be very funny, in a sad way, if you could crash Ethereum network with such a simple script.

Instead, you need to be prepared to spend a lot Ethers if you want to use the resources of public network extensively. As every state modifying transaction will cost you. Miners are happy to accept your money, or ignore your transactions.